# How to show grid with root in jqGrid in JSON

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I have a server that returns JSON in the following format:

```
[{"Name": "Student1", "Email": "Email1", "CellPhone": null},
{{"Name": "Student2", "Email": "Email2", "CellPhone": null}]
```

HTML file has:
    `<table id="list1></table>
    <div id="pager1"></div>`

JS file is:

```
jQuery().ready(function () {
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
        url: 'Default.aspx?query=SELECT VALUE s FROM ModelContainer.StudentSet AS s WHERE s.Name = \'Student2\'',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Name', 'Email'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 200 },
            { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 500 }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#pager1',
        sortname: 'Name',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "JSON Example",
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: true,
            id: "0",
            cell: "",
            //root: "",
            records: function (obj) {
                return obj.length;
            }
        }
    });
    jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager1',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
});
```

Since my JSON is already the root of data wanted, I don't know what to what with the `root` column. I've tried with not writing anything about root, or `root: ""`, neither has an output. But firebug shows that JSON is received correctly.

I don't know if this has anything to do with the root. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, we need to set the JSON object name in jsonReader as following:

```
jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: true,
            id: "0",
            cell: "",
            rows : "details",
            page : "pageno"
            }
```

**JSON FORMAT:**

```
 {"pageno":"1", "details" : [{"Name": "Student1", "Email": "Email1", "CellPhone": null},   
    {{"Name": "Student2", "Email": "Email2", "CellPhone": null}]
```

jsonreader options:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data

Comment: Does `id` in `jsonReader` mean line number? If so, what will happen if I write `id: "0"`?

Comment: No actually id is nothing but unique row id. Edited my answer please check.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "0",
    root:  function (obj) {
        return obj;
    },
    records: function (obj) {
        return obj.length;
    },
    page: function () {
        return 1;
    },
    total: function () {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

but to make the code which you posed working you have to fix more bugs:

- the HTML fragment

```html
<table id="list1></table> <div id="pager1"></div>
```

should be fixed to

```html
<table id="list1"></table> <div id="pager1"></div>
```

- The `jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({` should be fixed to `jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({`
- The JSON data must be fixed to remove syntax error because of one unneeded `{` character. Correct data can be

```json
[{"Name": "Student1", "Email": "Email1", "CellPhone": null},
 {"Name": "Student2", "Email": "Email2", "CellPhone": null}]
```

[The fixed demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Ovilia.htm) works.

Comment: @Bruno: Thank you! I agree with you. At the time it was 4.4.0 version of jqGrid. I suggested autodection of JSON format later. The feature exist starting with 4.4.5 version (and an important bug is fixed only in 4.5.0 version). So the accepted solution which uses `repeatitems: true` just can't work. Moreover the question was about **array of items** and the accepted answer suggest to change the format to `rows : "details"` instead of just usage of `root:  function (obj) {return obj;}` which would be the right way. Wrong accepted solution can confuse other readers, but I can't change it.